# js dataTable not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I dont know what is that im doing wrong. I have my normal table like this:

```
   <table id="table_list_values">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Seq
                </th>
                <th>
                   Order
                </th>
                <th>
                    Code
                </th>
                <th>
                    Description
                </th>
                <th>
                    Label Code
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

Nothing anormal. Then, populate the datatable i have to make an ajax call once I PRESS A BUTTOM(not before anything alse). That returns me alot of data but look how does the table is being display:
[image]

What do i have to do make it paginate? Here what I've tried:

**"bPagination:"**

```
  $('#ListValues').dataTable( {
    "bPaginate": true
  } );
```

**"bLengthChange"**

```
  $('#ListValues').dataTable( {
    "bLengthChange": false
  } );
```

Note: All of them are wrapped in `$(document).ready(function(){....})`

I have another table that work correctly by just adding `$("#Mytable").dataTable();`

[image]

What im doing wrong? If something else is need it, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The table id in your html is "table_list_values" and your datatable function is looking for #ListValues

Anytime you see a datatable that looks odd ie no paging, columns off, jquery ui styling not applied, odds are its the selector or table html

Answer (score 0):

if you want it to paginate, you need to set it to true on

```
 $('#ListValues').dataTable( {
    "bPaginate": true
  } );
```

Comment: Sorry, I setted it to true already. It was a mistake. I've updated my post

Comment: Your table id says <table id="table_list_values"> and youre calling #ListValues... make sure you have the correct ids